# BuildException: Failed to execute aapt

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-build

I am trying to build the project and following error is coming:

```
    org.gradle.tooling.BuildException: Failed to execute aapt
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask.invokeAaptForSplit(LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask.java:547)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask.doFullTaskAction(LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask.java:280)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.IncrementalTask.taskAction(IncrementalTask.java:106)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Error while executing process /home/local/MPROGA1/malwinder.singh/Desktop/SDK/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/27.0.1/aapt with arguments {package -f --no-crunch -I /home/local/MPROGA1/malwinder.singh/Desktop/SDK/android-sdk-linux/platforms/android-25/android.jar -M /home/local/MPROGA1/malwinder.singh/Desktop/Projects/Oversight/app/build/intermediates/manifests/full/debug/AndroidManifest.xml -S
```

When I try to run the application, following error comes:

> The APK file
>   /home/local/MPROGA1/malwinder.singh/Desktop/Projects/Oversight/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk
>   does not exist on disk. Error while Installing APK

Comment: I get a lot of times this kind of errors. Try to clean and rebuild your project, and remove the old version of this app from the device you are testing on, either emulator or device. Then try to make a clean install

Comment: see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48082586/buildexception-failed-to-execute-aapt-in-android-studio-3-1-canary-6/54615096#54615096). it might fix.

Answer (score 0):

> Have you tried using this in your

```
android.enableAapt2=false
```

> in your android **gradle properties**